# SSRS insert text when currency value ='GBP' or 'EURO' or 'USD' ect

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

i have been trying to work out how i can get a ssrs expression to insert text if the following currency appear in my invoices.

I would like,

if currency value  = 'GBP' then show text "please pay UK BANK 000x000x00"
if currency value  = 'Euro' then show text "please pay Euro BANK 000x000x00"

We have this to make the customer clear on which bank to pay into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SWITCH (similar to CASE in SQL) to display text based on the your value of the field. I have below an example with the sample you provided. Assuming your column name is "currency".

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!currency.value = "GBP", "please pay UK BANK 000x000x00",
Fields!currency.value = "Euro", "please pay Euro BANK 000x000x00")
```

Comment: Many thanks this worked just fine for me.